# Duplicated place names when rendering tiles with mapnik and mod_tile

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, mod-tile

So I am trying to render all the tiles for the state of Florida with the file `generate_tiles.py` that came with mapnik. The tiles are rendering, but erroneously including multiple city names (see below). Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Apopkas everywhere!]

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is with your database or mapnik style.

The first question is where you got the `.osm` file used to generate your database? May you check if it is ok?

The second one is how you generated your [Mapnik](https://mapnik.org/) style? May you can retry the process?

To answer these questions you need to verify if the database has repeated nodes or the mapnik style is incorrect.

To verify if your database doesn't have repeated city names, you can use (if you're using a database with the osm2pgsql schema) a SQL statement like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM planet_osm_point WHERE place IN ('city', 'town')
```

If your database and style are ok, you can try to follow this [tutorial](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04) to generate and render tiles with the stack Mod_tile, renderd, mapnik, osm2pgsql, and a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

You can also try to create a new mapnik style using tools like [Tilemill](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill) or [MapBox Studio Classic](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-classic) and the [openstreetmap-carto](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto) style and then verify if your problem is solved.